# Adding a Search Bar in Xcode with SwiftUi - In order to find a specific location within my list of Locations

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am getting this error when trying to add a Search Bar for a location App in Swift:

> "Error Cannot use instance member 'Location' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Error is occurring here:

```
private var listOfLocation = Location
```

Entire Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authentication: Authentication
    @State var searchText = ""
    private var listOfLocation = Location
    
    var body: some View {
        TabBar()
    }
    
    var Location: [String] {
        let lcLocations = listOfLocation.map { $0.lowercased() }
        
        return searchText == "" ? lcLocations : lcLocations.filter {
            $0.contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
    }
}
        
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(MapViewModel())
    }
}
```

I tried using a lazy var but still not working. I am new to Swift so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but it is common practice for variable names, function names, and case names to begin with lowercase letters. Class, struct, and enum names begin with uppercase letters.

Comment: Why assign a computed variable to a local variable in a view?  Not sure what your intent is

Comment: Your code has a bigger issue. Your `Location` var is based off of the value of the `listOfLocation` var. And you are trying to assign the value of `Location` to `listOfLocation`. That's just not something you should be trying to do. You should have one var that represents your full list of locations. And then you should have a second var that represents the filtered list of locations. But make no attempt to assign the filtered list var to the master list var.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback. I was able to solve the issue by adding the search function to my “LocationList”  file instead of the ContentView. In addition to adding the “@State” property to track the search query, I added a computed property to filter the “locations” array based on the search query.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LocationList: View {
    var locations: [Location]
    
    @State private var searchText = ""

    var filteredLocations: [Location] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return locations
        } else {
            return locations.filter { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("\(filteredLocations.count) \(filteredLocations.count > 1 ? "locations": "location" )")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .opacity(0.7)

                Spacer()

            
            }

            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160), spacing:15)], spacing: 15) {
                ForEach(filteredLocations) { location in
                    NavigationLink(destination: LocationView(location: location)) {
                        LocationCard(location: location)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.top)

        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
    }
}

struct LocationList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LocationList(locations: Location.all)
        }
    }
}
```